# AR - Filter Group Query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out why my query is not behaving the way I want it to. The following statement is trying to get the newest car in stock for each Ford model:

```
Car.where("make = 'Ford'").group(:model_id).having('year = MAX(year)')
```

But it seems to be grouping by `model_id` and then filtering by the year on all the data (not just for each group). This is the SQL it's generating:

```
SELECT `cars`.* FROM `cars` WHERE `cars`.`make` = 'Ford' GROUP BY model_id HAVING year = MAX(year)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different query I can use?

**Update**

Here is a sample of the data:

```
| make | model_id | year |
| Ford | 1        | 2000 |
| Ford | 1        | 2002 |
| Ford | 1        | 2010 |
| Ford | 2        | 2012 |
| BMW  | 3        | 2012 |
| BMW  | 4        | 2014 |
```

And it should return the following after the query:

```
| Ford | 1        | 2010 |
| Ford | 2        | 2012 |
```

Comment: You may want to read this article: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @p11y for posting a link that helped me solve the issue with the following query. Note: It may not be the most efficient. Please provide a more efficient query if you'd like.

```
subquery = "select max(year) from cars as c where c.model_id = cars.model_id"
Car.where("make = 'Ford' AND year = (#{subquery})")
```

**Update**: Adding subquery to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use aggregate functions as part of the SELECT clause, which should yield the desired result:

```
cars = Car.select('MAX(year)').group(:model_id)
cars.to_a.last.attributes
#=> {name: 'BMW', model_id: 4, ..., max: 2014}
```

you can use aliasing to select multiple aggregates at once:

```
cars = Car.select('MAX(year) as max_year, MAX(hp) as max_hp').group(:model_id)
cars.to_a.last.attributes
#=> {name: 'BMW', model_id: 4, ..., max_year: 2014, max_hp: 120}
```

In Postgresql, [you can use window functions](http://postgresguide.com/tips/window.html) to find extremes in the groups. It's not very pretty, but the result is a proper ActiveRecord relation that can be chained with other scopes:

```
Car.from('(SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY model_id ORDER BY year DESC) FROM cars) AS cars').where('rank = 1')
```

This can be refactored a bit for readability:

```
partition = 'PARTITION BY model_id ORDER BY year DESC'
subquery = Car.arel_table.project("*, rank() OVER (#{partition})")
Car.from("(#{subquery}) AS cars").where('rank = 1')
```

Now you can even do things like "get the two newest cars for each group":

```
Car.from("(#{subquery}) AS cars").where('rank <= 2')
```

Comment: It needs to be a relation. I don't want an array.

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk check my edit, you can use window functions in Postgres.

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with mysql. I would have to google it but i am sure you are capable of this yourself :)

Answer (score -1):

For starters, your expected results are impossible - you state that the query is for Fords, but you're expecting BMW's in the results.  I'm assuming this is a cut and paste error.

The problem you are facing is that you need to tell the `having` clause a bit more information about the query - namely, the max(year) for each group of the data you're interested in.

A sql query that in mysql pulls the results you want looks like this:

```
mysql> select make, model, max(year) as 'year' from cars group by model having year=max(year);
```

results:

```
+------+-------+------+
| make | model | year |
+------+-------+------+
| Ford |     1 | 2010 |
| Ford |     2 | 2012 |
| BMW  |     3 | 2012 |
| BMW  |     4 | 2014 |
+------+-------+------+
```

Translating this to active record, you need a query like:

```
Car.select('make, model, max(year) as year').group(:model).having('year = max(year)')
```

For fords only:

```
Car.select('make, model, max(year) as year').where(:model=>'Ford').group(:model).having('year = max(year)')
```

Comment: The BMW results were a mistake, sorry about that. What if you want to get Fords only?

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk add a where(:model=>'Ford') after the select() block